# Firebase Cloud Messaging format for cross-platform messages

Tags: android, ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm struggling to find a correct message format that works for both android and iOS.

Currently, I'm sending the following JSON object to the firebase-server:

```
{
   "to":"\/topics\/news",
   "data":{
      "notId":258,
      "title":"TestHeader",
      "message":"TestBody",
      "newsId":258,
      "tstamp":1540913340,
      "image":"https:\/\/example.com\/csm_2017-WM20IA_779f1c4f03.jpg"
   },
   "priority":"high"
}
```

This works great on android: A notification with the specified image is shown, the app is called to the foreground. 
On ios however, nothing happens. No notification is displayed and no event is triggered.

Adding this:

```
   "notification":{
      "title":"TestHeader",
      "body":"TestBody"
   },
```

to the object produces a notification on both android and iOS, but without an image, and without triggering the `notificationReceived` event.

How do I have to structure the JSON to get my desired output ( notification image, event handling, calling app to foreground ) on both iOS and android?

Answer (score 0):

for iOS notifications you need to include in the message the parameter **content_available: true**.

```
    {
       "to":"\/topics\/news",
       "content_available" : true,
       "data":{
          "notId":258,
          "title":"TestHeader",
          "message":"TestBody",
          "newsId":258,
          "tstamp":1540913340,
          "image":"https:\/\/example.com\/csm_2017-WM20IA_779f1c4f03.jpg"
       },
       "priority":"high"
    }
```

Please check the official documentation [Firebase message syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json)

[image]

Best regards.